# load images using url in grid View

Tags: android

I am new to android studio . I want to make wallpaper app in which load images from internet using images url in gridView.  For this I create activity_common

activty_common.xml

```
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:id="@+id/gridView" />
```

custom_layout

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/lion"/>
```

then I create  Gridadapter

```
public class Gridadapter  extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public String mThumbIds[];

public Gridadapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(480, 480));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    String url = getItem(position);
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(url)
            .centerCrop().into(imageView);
    return imageView;
}}
```

then i create java class named Food

```
 public class Food extends Activity {

public String[] mThumbIds = {
       " https://www.pexels.com/photo/daylight-environment-fog-forest-539945/",
"https://www.pexels.com/photo/daylight-environment-fog-forest-539945/"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activtiy_common);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    //  Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new Gridadapter(this, mThumbIds));


}
```

}

I think gridadapter  allow Integer[];
how can i pass String[];
i add internet premissiona and picasso library

when is run app it's gave me
Error:(28, 29) error: constructor Gridadapter in class Gridadapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: Food,String[]

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Thanks in advance

Comment: error in only in Food.java class

Answer (score 0):

getting error because in your adapter class there is only one parameter in your Gridadapter and you passing two parameter from your activity

**just change your Gridadapter constructor like this**

```
public Gridadapter(Context c,String[]Food) {
    mContext = c;
    mThumbIds=food;
}
```

Comment: share your exception

Comment: only  error in  class  Food .java  and the code is below   gridView.setAdapter(new Gridadapter(this, mThumbIds));

Comment: yes just change constructor in your adapter class and your error  will be solved

Comment: **this constructor** `public Gridadapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}` my friend

Answer (score 0):

your adapter constructor shoulb be;

```
public Gridadapter(Context c,String[] mThumbIds) {
    mContext = c;
mThumbIds = mThumbIds;

}
```

Comment: it's work .but now  unfortunately app has stopped the exception is  below 
   08-29 08:01:30.606 58-58/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
08-29 08:01:30.606 58-58/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
08-29 08:01:30.606 58-58/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
08-29 08:01:30.606 58-58/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
08-29 08:01:30.610 58-58/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
08-29 08:01:30.610 58-58/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
08-29 08:01:30.614 58-58/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
08-29 08:01:30.622 58-58/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request
08-29 08:01:30.626 58-58/? W/Genyd: Can't parse request

Answer (score 0):

You have passed two parameters in **Gridadapter(this, mThumbIds)** but in your adapter class, you have defined only one parameter.
Modify your adapter class:

```
public Gridadapter(Context c,String mThumbIds[]) {
    mContext = c;
    this.mThumbIds[] = mThumbIds[];
}
```